# Python Tweepy Bot that randomly tweets image and a corresponding text caption from a json file

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I am trying to create a Twitter bot that tweets a random caption and corresponding image from a json file every 30 minutes. So far I have:

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
import random

import json
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    info = json.load(f)

print('Twitter Bot')

CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXX'
ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


randomChoice = random.randrange(len(info))
print (info[randomChoice])
api.update_status(status=info[randomChoice])
```

Json File:

```
    [
  {
    "text": "hi",
    "image": "/image1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "text": "hello",
    "image": "/image2.jpg"
  }
]
```

But the tweet only shows: {'text': 'hello', 'image': '/image2.jpg'}. How can I make it so that only the image and text are shown? Also, how do I set it so that this happens every 30 minutes? I am new to programming and would appreciate any help that is provided!

Comment: You need something like this: `api.update_with_media(info[randomChoice]['image'], status=info[randomChoice]['text'])`. However, you need to be sure either 1) the image files are in the current working directory, or 2) you supply the full path to the image files.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. How would I go about automatically tweeting every 30 minutes with this?

Comment: You're very welcome. I posted an answer with more information about how to run the code every 30 minutes. Best wishes with it!

Comment: Excellent! I am grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
api.update_with_media(info[randomChoice]['image'], 
                      status=info[randomChoice]['text'])
```

However, you need to be sure either:

1. the image files are in the current working directory, or
2. you supply the full path to the image files.

To handle running this every 30 minutes, you can use [the `schedule` module](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/):

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")
    # your tweepy code here 

schedule.every(30).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```